# Upload photos to Facebook page (not personal profile)

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management, facebook

A couple of the various Linux photo organizer applications (Shotwell & f-spot, at least) let you upload pictures to Facebook, but as far as I can see, that's limited only to albums on your personal page. Am I just missing something, and it is actually possible to use either Shotwell or f-spot to upload to albums in a page you are an administrator for? If not, is there another Picasa-type program that has this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shotwell can't currently do this.  I've ticketed it: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2942

I'm not sure Facebook makes uploading to group pages available via their API.  If they do, I'd like to see this feature.

Note that if you upload to your personal account, you can add those photos to a group you administer without re-uploading them through the browser.

Comment: The Facebook API provides this permission -- 
  
    **manage_pages** Enables your application to retrieve access_tokens for pages the user administrates. The access tokens can be queried using the "accounts" connection in the Graph API. This permission is only compatible with the Graph API -- 
  
which at least suggests that it may be possible.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for thinking about adding this to Shotwell.

Answer (score 5):

@fluteflute is not totally wrong. It is right that, BY DEFAULT Picasa doesn't support Facebook (or Gallery2, Flickr or anything other than Picasaweb), but Picasa is extendable and has several modules to do so:

- http://apps.facebook.com/picasauploader/
- http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/picasa2flickr-upload-photos-from-picasa.html
- http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2:Modules:picasa

I've never used the Facebook or Flickr modules but the gallery2 one, yes, and it's not so easy to install at all, but it works.

So to answer Steve K, yes, you can use Picasa to upload your pictures to Facebook, but with the installation of a specific module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a page to try that so I can't tell, but you might want to try Digikam, which has a good uploader.

If all else fails, Picasa is available on Ubuntu, although not open-source.